# Trying to set Estimote iBeacon GPIO pin .high - SWIFT iOS

Tags: ios, swift, gpio, estimote

Ive been trying for a few days now to set a pin high (Estimote location beacon) from an app I'm building. 
Im doing something wrong as i am getting an error when the block fires off. Error is: [ESTTelemetryInfo portsData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...
Ive looked everywhere for a snippet but can't find anything. I only want to be able to set the pin high (i don't need to send any data). If i can set the pin high i figure i could set it low when done using the same methods. This is the code:

```
let telem = ESTTelemetryInfo.init(shortIdentifier: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")!
let setPinHigh = ESTTelemetryNotificationGPIO.init(notificationBlock: { (telemInfo) in
if telInfo.shortIdentifier! != "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" { return }
telemInfo.portsData.setPort(.port0, value: .high)
})
setPinHigh.fireNotificationBlock(with: telem)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
ps Sorry if this is incorrectly formatted (long time reader first time poster).
Cheers
Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed..we'll sort of. For anyone wanting to know the right way to to set a pin high, in output mode, is to connect to the beacon first through the device manager: ESTDeviceManager() -set the delegate in the class as ESTDeviceManagerDelegate - startDeviceDiscovery(with: deviceFilter) then in the delegate method:
    func estDeviceConnectDidSucceed(_ device: ESTDeviceConnectable) {    self.settings.gpio.portsData.setPort(.port0, value: .high)
}
BUT -> at the moment there is a bug that portsData has no member 'setPort'. I've filed a bug issue with Estimote on GitHub. Will come back to report once it's fixed.